# Why std::fstream returns void instead of bool

Tags: c++

Why member function open of std::fstream class from C++ Standard Library returns void instead of bool for immediately checking succesful opening?

Comment: returning bool isn't necessarily obvious in what that means: It could either mean "return true if error occured" as well as "return true if successful". There are different design choices. There is no way to get .isGood() or isBad() wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Because it throws exceptions when the `open` call was not successful if exceptions are set, or they use `failbit` to indicate an error occurred. From the documentation:

> On failure, the failbit flag is set (which can be checked with member
>   fail), and depending on the value set with exceptions an exception may
>   be thrown.

Comment: It will throw only if exceptions were set

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Added to the answer for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that there are so many ways fstream could fail when its allowing you to attempt to read (or I suppose write also) any type of file.  Also "failure" could be ambiguous depending on the situation and the programmer.  Given that, I think it would be difficult to get anything meaningful out of a boolean return value.